# DataTable Not working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have listed all users in my view Like follows:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $user = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('admin.users.index',['users'=>$user]);
    }
}
```

//view is

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%"   cellspacing="0" id="table">
   //Loop here
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

It's Giving me error:

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I did most of R&D but did not find it working. Please assist what could be the Issue in this.

Is there anything I need to do with this, because I already used it same in symfony2 it is working there.

Even I followed [this](http://justlaravel.com/how-to-implement-datatables-in-laravel/) as well.

Thank Advance

Comment: Within your console: is there a 404?

Comment: check if datatable script includes properly or not?

Comment: <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"</script>
?? its not closed

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: its closed in actual code..

Comment: yes, if I view the page source all libs are included properly..

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: script is closed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

 

  

     <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

               <thead>
         <tr>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th >Email</th>
            <th >Joined</th>
             <th colspan="2">Action1</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
            <th >Email</th>
            <th >Joined</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>go</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th> Name </th>
            <th> Email </th>
            <th> Joined </th>
            <th>Action1</th>
                <th>Action2</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<td>a</td> 
<td>b</td> 
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td> 
<td>e</td>   </tr>
          </tbody>
            </table>
```

this is a working example i think problem in script include its need http and table 
the table **colspan** usage According to dataTable 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Comment: I dont understand why not working on my page. even all thing included properly. this example even not working. is there any issue with Laravel blade template?

Comment: did you change table ? i mean does it print correctly form laravel ?
inspect code and put the out come of your loop then we will resolve it

Comment: <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="example">

 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );

yes, like above

Comment: i mean the result of loop and the current error and it shall not be  
this TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
any more

Comment: No, result is comming properly. I did not make any changes loop and query. Just want to apply dataTable to render Table data,

Comment: can you print the result table from inspect ?? change values if it senstive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129431/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-jehad-ahmad-jaghoub).

Comment: When I removed colspan which was given, in <th> is is working on simple page, but when I did same thing in my laravel view its still giving same error. Might be some issue of Laravel..

Comment: don remove any thing keep colspan
 <thead>
         <tr>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th >Email</th>
            <th >Joined</th>
             <th colspan="2">Action1</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
            <th >Email</th>
            <th >Joined</th>
            <th>edit</th>
            <th>go</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

so what you need is to reintroduce th again in head to make it understand clospan like example above run code its working 100% and if you don't like double title keep first blank

Comment: Thank for you cooperation dude. The issue is in layout file when I remove layout from my view then it works. but in layuot file I do not have any further library used, then not able to understand why stilll same error. plz check my layout in chat

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your script tags properly :)

`<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Comment: it is `DataTable();`

Comment: I have tried this as well:
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table').DataTables();
        } );
TypeError: $(...).DataTables is not a function

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"</script>
```

Please complete the script tag.